# Loop through an excel range using a for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I am creating a `*.xlsx` document using PHPExcel, and I'm trying to loop through a load of cells in a range. I can split the cells to get the first and last in the range, but is it possible to loop through them using a PHP `for` loop? Thanks.

```
$first_cell = 'A4';
$last_cell = 'M4';

for(...) :

endfor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
foreach (range('A','M') as $letter) {

    $current=$letter.'4'
    // where $current is the cell you are doing stuff to in the loop iteration
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I'd have to first extract the first and last letters, as well as the number (they are taken from a worksheet, as opposed to declared as I did above), but I can do that and it would work. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard, Glad I could help. Should be nothing more than splitting the string by letter and number and taking into account double of either number and letter. If you need to do things with multiple columns just wrap it in a for loop.